# Why can Wordpress ship with latest version of jQuery but Drupal cant?

Tags: javascript

Just a general question to as what holds Drupal back from being able to use the latest version of jQuery? I am guessing it is something technical but would like some details.

Even jquery update module only updates a few versions for Drupal 7 it goes for 1.4.4 to 1.5.2 while Wordpress ships with 1.7.1

- Drupal 6 to jQuery 1.3.2
- Drupal 7 to jQuery 1.5.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.11

Comment: You can add one more jQuery copy for your Drupal pages, if needed. For example, core will work with old version by you will write javascript code and use plugins for jQuery 1.7.1 on pages you need.

Comment: @kalabro -- I'm not a big fan of this method, it can often cause pretty big script errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that the version of jQuery gets locked down with the version of Drupal during development to ensure stability. It is all part of the testing process. The Drupal developers fully test the system before releasing a new major version of the CMS, including the JavaScript functionality. The incremental changes that go on throughout the year do not provide the time to test at this level so the jQuery version stays the same.

I am not very familiar with Wordpress, but my understanding is that they make considerably more regular major upgrades to the versions of their CMS. So jQuery gets updated more frequently. However, from [what I've read](http://kevinjohngallagher.com/2012/01/wordpress-has-left-the-building/) little testing takes place.

While getting stuck with an old version of jQuery can be frustrating, I'd rather go for a stable well tested system.

Comment: That link came via http://john.albin.net/drupal/dont-get-cocky-kid which is also a good read.

Answer (score 0):

The project page for JQuery update module is [not quite up to date](http://drupal.org/node/1386294#comment-5484220). Have a look at [this issue / patch](http://drupal.org/node/1386294#comment-5422788):  -- It's still be worked on so use with care but it looks promising and it looks like it's getting attention and recent as well.

In your tags you did not specify what version of Drupal you are using though, the issue above is for Drupal 7. (That's one of the gotchas of Drupal, sometimes lurking around in the issue queues can yeield some nice finds and solutions that may not be evident yet on a module/s project page.